# Arguments not being passed correctly to Test::MockObject method

Tags: perl, unit-testing

I'm working on setting up a test script in Perl. I'm using Test::MockObject to create a mock object which will hold some configuration data. The configuration in the live program comes from an INI file, i.e. it has the format

```
[SECTION]
KEY = VALUE
```

As such, I've set up the following:

```
use Test::MockObject;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

use constant SECTION_NAME => 'section';
use constant KEY_NAME => 'key';
use constant VALUE_NAME => 'value';

my $com_mock = Test::MockObject->new();

$com_mock->mock( 'getIniVar', sub {
   my $self = shift;
   my ( $section, $key ) = @_;
   print STDERR "\$_[0] = '" . Dumper( $_[0] ) ." '\n";
   print STDERR "\$_[1] = '" . Dumper( $_[1] ) ." '\n";  
   my %iniVar = ( SECTION_NAME => { KEY_NAME => VALUE_NAME } );
   return( $iniVar{$section}->{$key} );
} );

$self->{com} = $com_mock;
```

Later, I actually call the mocked function:

```
print STDERR
      "\$self->{com}->getIniVar( 'section', 'key') = '"
    . $self->{com}->getIniVar( SECTION_NAME,KEY_NAME )
    . "'\n";
```

When I run the test, I see the following:

```
ok 1 - use Appriss::ImageExtraction3::Config;
$_[0] = '$VAR1 = 'section';
 '
$_[1] = '$VAR1 = 'key';
 '
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at t/config/config.pm line 159.
$self->{com}->getIniVar( 'section', 'key') = ''
$_[0] = '$VAR1 = undef;
 '
$_[1] = '$VAR1 = 'key';
 '
```

The first time that the mock object is called is during

```
use_ok 'Appriss::ImageExtraction3::Config';
```

This seems to have all of the arguments that I want, but I'm not explicitly calling that, so I don't know what's happening there. The second time is when I explicitly call it using

```
$self->{com}->getIniVar( SECTION_NAME,KEY_NAME )
```

(Shown above)... and at this point, the first argument is set to undef... why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line looks suspicious:

```
my ( $section, $key ) = @_;
```

As I understand, the first argument should be the mock object itself.

As for P.S., you can run t/*.t files individually:

```
% perl -Ilib -d t/13-unlucky.t
```

Comment: Yes, the 'my($section, $key) = @_;' part is wrong... the problem is that even when I shift the object off of the argument stack, the next argument is null.

Comment: I ended up using `perl -d -I blib/lib -I t/lib t/config/config.pm` ... I'm using Test::Class, which I stuck in t/lib, and the test suite was generated by h2xs, so it uses the blib directory tree to create a temporary environment for testing. Unfortunately, Test::Class wraps a lot of the test code inside an eval, and the debugger doesn't traverse evaled code.  +1/4 internets for `t/13-unlucky.t`

Comment: I fixed getIniVar so that it uses `my $self=shift;` before `my ( $section, $key ) = @_;`... I'm still losing the first argument after $self.

Comment: @BartonChittenden Hm, what about injecting a `Carp::cluck("I'm here");` into the mock sub? You'll get a stack trace that might be helpful.

Comment: I think that cracked it. The mocked function was being called by two different methods. One was directly inside the test (which worked), the other was inside the class that I was testing, which didn't work. Apparently I have a hash that didn't get passed in correctly. It wasn't until I could look at the call stack left by Carp::cluck that I could see exactly where the mocked method was being called. Definitely one to add to the bag o' tricks. I still have to figure out exactly where the hash in question needs to be passed in, but that's now doable.

Comment: @BartonChittenden FYI: There's also `local $SIG{__DIE__} = \&Carp::cluck;` - horrible for production, but sometimes extremely handy for debugging.